# Physics differential equations problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I am told that a torpedo is fired and has an initial velocity of 60 km/hr. After 1 km travelled, its velocity falls to 30 km/hr. We know that the drag force acting on the body is proportional to the speed of the body (at low speeds). Disregarding everything else, I need to find the total distance travelled.

I've tried this:

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=k\frac{dy}{dt} \\
\frac{dv}{dt}=kv \\
ln(v)=kt+c_{1} \\
v = 60\ e^{kt}\ , \ (k < 0) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = 60\ e^{kt} \\
y = \frac{60}{k}(1-e^{kt}) + c_{2} \\
y(0) = 0 \\
y = \frac{60}{k}(1-e^{kt})
$$

So after taking the limit, the distance travelled is $\frac{60}{k}$. Still, I need to find the $k$ to get the exact result. Since this is a Math problem rather than a Physics one, I know I should use the given distance and speed to find $k$, but I can't find where to use it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two expressions, one for speed and one for distance:
$$
v=60e^{-kt}\\
y=\frac{60}k\left(1-e^{-kt}\right)
$$
Note that we can expand and perform a substitution:
$$
y=\frac 1k\left(60-60e^{-kt}\right)\\
y=\frac 1k(60-v)
$$
We've already substituted in the initial condition, so let's substitute the other ($v_{y=1}=30$):
$$
1=\frac 1k(60-30)\\
k=30
$$
So the final answer is simply:
$$
y_{t=\infty}=\frac{60}k=\frac{60}{30}=2
$$

Comment: Perfect. I was trying to find somewhere to relate position and velocity without time but couldn't get it. Simple and correct. Thanks!